# how to make batch file to popup messagebox that asks for admin permission?

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I want to Install My sql using No-Installer on multiple customer's machines, for which i have created a batch file.. but running this batch file , gives error as Install/Remove is denied.. running batch file with "runas/user:pc\administrator" asks for password, but gives error if password is blank(admin do not have any password saved)...
So what i am looking for is a way to popup a messagebox(just like one which popups when bat file is right clicked and opened as administrator) but programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/usermessages.php)'s method to prompt for a password :

Grab this : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/ielogin2_vbs.txt

And use it like this :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=  " %%a in ('cscript.exe //NoLogo ielogin2.vbs') do set $password=%%˜b

echo The password is %$password%
```

Another method from Rob van der Woude (without hiding the password) :

```
> pwd.vbs echo WScript.Echo InputBox( "Password ?", "Password ?", "" )
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript.exe //NoLogo pwd.vbs') do set $password=%%a
del pwd.vbs

echo The password is %$password%
```

[Horst Schaeffer](http://www.horstmuc.de/w32dial.htm#winput)'s Winput :

Grab this : http://www.horstmuc.de/win/winput.zip

And use it like this :

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('winput.exe "$input" "Password ?" /pass') do set $password=%%a

echo The password is %$password%
```

Microsoft/Sysinternals [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to start something with a login/password on a local or remote computer :

```
psexec.exe \\computer -u login -p password c:\myscript.bat
```

PowerAdmin [PAExec](https://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/), the Redistributable version of PsExec, with a little bit more security (not sure about the syntax) :

```
paexec.exe \\computer -p@password.txt -p@d c:\myscript.bat
```

Joeware [CPAU](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/), the big gun of alternate security context. Create your job with login/password and encrypt it into a specific file.

```
cpau.exe -u login -p password -ex "c:\myscript.bat" -enc -file myscript.job

cpau.exe -dec -file myscript.job -lwp
```

And of course, PowerShell is [never](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/11/masking-passwords-in-windows-powershell.aspx) [far away](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/04/how-can-i-mask-passwords-using-an-inputbox.aspx).

Comment: Thanks 
Frederic.. It will be helpful :)